# How to Host a Flask website from localhost 5000

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, localhost, hosting

Hello I coded this website that generates math problems (Here is the code: [Here](https://github.com/some0ne14/Math-Ibex))

It is coded on flask and it is locally being hosted on this link that is not accessible to other people http://127.0.0.1:5000/ .I have a google domain and I want to have a website. What things / services do I need to use. I have been wait to see if I need to use AWS but I think I might need to. I have tried things like transferring it off of flask but I can't. If this is a repost sorry please post there answer thanks -Ben

Comment: there's a lot to explain here, TLDR to give google keywords: 1) make domain DNS to point to your IP (hoping you have a static one, but you might need to set up port forwarding on your router and/or dynamic DNS) 2) serve on an accessible interface - 127.0.0.1 is a local loopback, you need to serve on the external one (your external IP) or 0.0.0.0 (all interfaces). 3) [optional but desireable] set up a and configure through a normal webserver, like nginx or Apache

Comment: Also, do not post secret keys / config variables in the code. The simplest alternative is to use [environment variables](https://developers.refinitiv.com/en/article-catalog/article/how-to-separate-your-credentials--secrets--and-configurations-fr)

Comment: Thanks for contributing @Marat I am some what new to code so could you post a link to put me in the right direction thanks -Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming what you're asking is to host your flask web site so others can view it.  The address you mention in your post is the local host address for your computer and is only accessible from your own computer.  If you only want someone on your same network (WiFi) to access it, you would need to replace "127.0.0.1" with the IP address of your computer.  You would also likely have to open up a firewall on your computer to allow the port 5000.

However, if you want anyone on the internet to access your site, there are a ton of ways to do this but since you mentioned AWS, you can do this easily by running a small EC2 instance (virtual server).  If you have a new AWS account and have not already run any EC2 in that account, you can actually run a small EC2 instance for free for a whole year.  Great for small projects.  If you're just getting started with EC2, you may want to go here https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/getting-started/

Basic steps:

1. Spin up an EC2 instance. Choose the default Amazon Linxu 2 OS type, make sure to create/assign a key pair so you can later ssh into it, make sure the Allow SSH from anywhere setting is checked/selected and the Allow HTTP checkbox is checked (not HTTPS).
2. Wait for the instance to launch.
3. Log into your instance by clicking on your ec2 instance in the list of ec2 instnaces and click the Connect button, click the Connect button again (Instance connect tab). If that doesn't work, follow the steps on the SSH client tab.
4. Install flask

```
pip3 install flask
```

5. Clone your git repo

```
git clone https://github.com/some0ne14/Math-Ibex.git
```

6. Change to your repos' folder

```
cd Math-Ibex/Math-Practice-Website-master
```

7. Edit your main.py so that the app.run line looks like the following (you can do this on GitHub before you run git clone actually or use the `nano` command to edit the file easily). This allows the system to run on the standard web port 80.

```
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80, debug=True)
```

8. Run the following to start the application. If you want to run it as a service so you can walk away or close the terminal and it will still stay running, just search on here how to run flask as a service.

```
python3 main.py
```

9. You can now connect to your server with any web browser using your EC2 instance's public IP address or generated AWS DNS name (available on the EC2 instnace property page).
10. Make sure to stop your instance when not using it to save those free runtime minutes.

Comment: Sorry @JoeW like I said I am still pretty new to code I was able to have the website instance run on this link "http://10.0.0.28/" I just do not understand the last part to make it public. I tried to follow your directions but I do understand part 9 and 10. Thanks for understanding - Ben

Comment: @SOMEONE14 - If you have everything running up through step 8, you can open another browser tab to the EC2 console [link](https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/v2/home?#Instances:instanceState=running) and select you istance in the list.  At the bottom you can see details, what you're looking for is Public IPv4 address or Public DNS Name.  I'm not sure the exact name of the fields there but something similar.  If you don't see any address listed, then your instance is somehow in a private subnet or has not been assigned a public IP.  Note, 10.x.x.x addresses can't be accessed on the internet.